# Windows Phone OS 7.0 "vanilla" name

Tags: windows-phone-7

With WP 7.1 "Mango" coming out I find myself in a need to efficiently address WP 7.0.

As such, is there a codename for the original version?

Possible (bad) candidates:

- "RTM"; but that is usually used to a very specific version. Furthermore you could also have "Windows Phone 7.1 RTM" for the Mango version released to OEMs
- "Vanilla"; This would fit in the food-name of Mango, but usually refers to an unmodified version of an OS/ROM so isn't the best choise. (e.g. "My Phone runs on the vanilla ROM, I don't need custom ROMs" or "Dell made some changes to the vanilla version")

edit:
Possible names based on keyboardP's answer:

- "NoDo" and "pre-NoDo" to refer to the OS 7.0 versions after an before the "No Donuts" update
- "Launch" to name the original (i.e. pre-NoDo update of 7.0)

Personally I'm gonna use "Launch", "NoDo" and "Mango", but of course you can make your own choises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a codename for the launch version of WP7. I'd say `WP 7.0` pretty much refers to it. Of course, there is some granularity which allows a device to be `pre-NoDo` or `NoDo` depending on if they've been updated. Other than that, I haven't come across a codename for WP 7.0 that's been publicly used.

Comment: NoDo and pre-NoDo would work. I'm accepting this unless someone comes up with a better one

Comment: "Launch" would of course also be a good name, especially for pre-NoDo

Comment: Indeed Windows Phone 7 doesn't have a codename found this out myself recently when I was doing some research for a presentation - closest was Photon which was codename for the follow up to Windows Mobile 6.5 which was replaced by WP7 but wouldn't apply - Launch sounds fine to me

Answer (score 0):

I think we will (should?) forget codenames. Remember Whidbey, Orcas, Indigo, Longhorn? Hardly being used after their releases. Windows Phone 7 and Windows Phone 7.5 (consumer/marketing names) should work.
Other than that, it could be referred as Mango, and Pre-Mango.

Comment: Codenames might not be used by the general public, they're certainly used a lot by developers since it is easier using a word than a number.

E.g. I use Ubuntu names more often than their numbers.